# Create Vertical Menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I am try do a menu like the photo below:

[image: This is the menu I am trying do]

I have this code:

```
    <Menu >
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="Item1">
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1">
                <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.2"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.3"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.4"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 4"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Item2">
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

but this code returns a menu like in the pictures below:

First appears this:

[image]

and when I put the mouse hover the Item 1 appears like this:

[image]

I want to that the second level of the Menu open on the right side of the first, like in the first image.

Comment: I guess you're untill now having the Y point set to be match the height of the Item that is triggering the ShowComment event. And, it matches the first menu! What else would be the code? I think you can do that, by, giving the height, equal to the total size of the menu.

Comment: I didn't understand correctly can you give me an example?

Comment: Set the location of the submenu to match the top border of the Main Menu!

Comment: give me a code example please?

Comment: A `Menu` is meant to create a menu strip like the one that runs beneath the title bar of a standard Windows application.  Are you trying to create a popup menu?  If so, your top-level menu should be a `ContextMenu`.

Comment: Have how I put a ContextMenu fixed in a Side of my screen?

Comment: Ah, so this *is* supposed to be a fixed menu?

Comment: yes, is fixed on the left side of the screen

Comment: I believe you'll have to create a custom template for the top-level menu header (see `MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey`), and within the template, have the menu's `Popup` placement set to `Right`.

Comment: you don't have a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a custom template for your `Menu` to achieve your goal.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx) is the default `ControlTemplate` for Menu, I think the easiest way is to start from that. You will have to add `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset` for the `PopUp` in the `TopLevelHeader` template, so you can align it to your needs (or simply set `Placement` to `Right` - which is easier in my opinion).

Also, you should set a `Width` for your menu (either directly or by placing it inside some container that restricts it's `Width`), otherwise it will take up all the space and the PopUp might not be visible .

I will not replicate the whole XAML here, but here is the important part:

```
// ...
<!-- TopLevelHeader -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
             TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" >
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter 
                    Margin="6,3,6,3" 
                    ContentSource="Header"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                  <Popup 
                    Name="Popup"
                    Placement="Right"  <!-- This is modified -->
                    IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                    AllowsTransparency="True" 
                    Focusable="False"
                    PopupAnimation="Fade">
// ... (You need all the XAML from the linked MSDN site in your Resources somewhere)
```

After that you can use your `Menu` almost exactly like you did (I only added `Width`):

```
<Menu Width="300">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="Item1">
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1">
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.1"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.2"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.3"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1.4"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 4"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Item2">
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

You might want to name the template and apply it to this `Menu` directly, not to mess up other `Menus` in your app...

The result:

[image: vertical menu]

Of course some more styling is needed to get the exact result you want, but I hope you got the idea.